# AdapterView.OnItemClickListener is not working

Tags: java, android

```
AdapterView.OnItemClickListener itemClickListener=new
    AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> listView, int position, View v, long id) {
            if (position == 0) {
                Intent intent=new Integer(TopLevelActivity.this, DrinkCategoryActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        }
    };
```

Comment: It shows me the red line on "new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()"

Comment: Are you using Xamarin? If not, Java method names usually start with lowercase characters (i.e. `onItemClickListener`)

Comment: Can you include the code where are you assigning the `itemClickListener` to anything ?

Answer (score 1):

lets assume that your `AdapterView` is `ListView`

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        if (position == 0) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(TopLevelActivity.this, DrinkCategoryActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set your listener to your `ListView`. That is the reason why it is not working.

Do it like this:

```
AdapterView.OnItemClickListener itemClickListener = 
      new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {  ... }; // create listener (you did that already)

listView.setOnItemClickListener(itemClickListener); // set listener
```

Comment: i already fixed it, but ty for your reply. it was the same problem.